# Solution of $\sin(xk)\cos(x)-s=\cos(xk)\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let's assume $s\neq 0$.
>
> Do exists a $x\neq m\pi$ with $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and a $k\in\mathbb{N_{>0}}$ such that the equation $$\sin(xk)\cos(x)-s=\cos(xk)\sin(x)$$ is satisfied?

I don't think that there exist such values $x,k$ at all.

I have already tried to start with some assumptions like $\cos(x)<\sin(x)$ and produce a contradiction by using trigonometric identities but so far I haven't made any progress. Maybe someone else has a good idea?

Comment: Hint: What is $\sin(kx+x)$?

Comment: Use sin A cos B - cos A sin B = sin(A-B)

Answer (score 1):

This is the equation $\sin(kx-x)=s$, which is satisfied if and only if $-1\le s\le 1$ and there is some $j\in\Bbb Z$ such that $(k-1)x=2j\pi+\arcsin s$ or $(k-1)x=(2j+1)\pi-\arcsin s$. Hence there are of pairs $(x,k)$ with that property except when there aren't.